# PayPal JavaScript Client SDK - Create Order - purchase units array - is there a custom parameter

Tags: paypal, payment

There doesn't seem to be a "custom" parameter available to the PayPal JavaScript V2 Client SDK.
Is there an alternative that will allow me to send a custom value?

My current set up to initialize the button is:

```
<script>

  function initPayPalButton() {
    paypal.Buttons({
      style: {
        shape: 'rect',
        color: 'gold',
        layout: 'vertical',
        label: 'paypal',
      },

      createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.create({
          purchase_units: [{"description":"Premium Service","amount":{"currency_code":"USD","value":10.99}}]
        });
      },

   . . . . Other code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is in fact, actions.order.create() is a [v2/checkout/orders create](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_create), with all the same parameters including `custom_id`

---

However if you are making use of such a parameter for anything important, it's a sign that you likely should be using [the server-side pattern](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) , with calls to "Create Order" and "Capture Order" [from your back end.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls)

Comment: I found the documentation for the [purchase_unit_request object](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2#definition-purchase_unit_request)  that does have the `custom_id`  setting.

Comment: Does the server-side integration have the "in-app" PayPal dialog or does it open a new tab in the browser?

Comment: The client-side and server-side integrations are exactly the same in this respect (same JS, only difference is the latter pattern does a fetch to your server).  See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/info-security-guidelines/#secure-applications -- you can use a Safari View Controller or Chrome Custom Tab. You cannot use a WKWebView or similar.

Comment: I used the code from the [PayPal Server side pattern](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server) and I can get server calls to the PayPal API to return information, like the authorization token and a created order, and order id but the the client side PayPal code constantly has an error.  It doesn't look like that page for the is available anymore PayPal Server side pattern through the website.  And I don't see any other documentation for integrating the client side SDK with server side calls.  But solving this problem is for a different question obviously.

Comment: I suppose, since I don't know what problem you're describing. The same integration is documented at the bottom of any of the pages at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls , just without the error handling

Comment: Interesting. quote:  *(Optional) Handle creating and capturing an order on your server. . . . .  rather than using the client-side functions that the JavaScript provides. Remove `createOrder` and `captureOrder` from the JavaScript and create server-side API calls.* end quote.  See end of section: [set-up-standard-payments-add-payment-buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/#1-add-payment-buttons) I've figured out how to create an order with the REST API, so I can get the order ID, and then complete the order from the `onApprove` method.  Hopefully.